# Rendering tikz graphics using Tikzit and MacOS

Tags: tikz-pgf, mac

I wanted to try using "Tikzit" for MacOS to create some simple diagrams without too much hassle. Running the below code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzit}
\usepackage{tikz}
\input{mystyle.tikzstyles}
\begin{document}
  \tikzfig{density.tikz}
\end{document}
```

using the following `mystyle.tikzstyles`

```
% TiKZ style file generated by TikZiT. You may edit this file manually,
% but some things (e.g. comments) may be overwritten. To be readable in
% TikZiT, the only non-comment lines must be of the form:
% \tikzstyle{NAME}=[PROPERTY LIST]

% Node styles
\tikzstyle{red dot}=[fill={rgb,255: red,45; green,100; blue,189}, draw=black, shape=circle]
\tikzstyle{new style 0}=[fill=white, draw=black, shape=circle]

% Edge styles
\tikzstyle{new edge style 0}=[->]
\tikzstyle{dashed}=[-, dashed]
```

And using the following `density.tikz`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{nodelayer}
        \node [style=none] (0) at (-2, 0) {};
        \node [style=none] (1) at (2, 0) {};
        \node [style=red dot] (2) at (0.5, 3.25) {};
        \node [style=new style 0] (3) at (0.5, 0.75) {};
        \node [style=none] (4) at (-2, -0.5) {};
        \node [style=none] (5) at (2, -0.5) {};
    \end{pgfonlayer}
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{edgelayer}
        \draw [bend left=60, looseness=1.25] (0.center) to (1.center);
        \draw [style=new edge style 0] (3) to (2);
        \draw [style=dashed, in=120, out=60, looseness=1.25] (4.center) to (5.center);
    \end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and Tikzit as downloaded from Github: https://tikzit.github.io/

Everything seems to work fine, except when rendering PDF/the image, I'm only seeing a red "box" containing the text "density.tikz" inside the document. I'm not very MacOS savvy and thus I'm not sure how to proceed with this kind of problem.

[image]

I'm running the latest MacOS Mojave build, 18G95 and the tex distribution for this year.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The extension is automatically added to the argument for `\tikzfig`, so when you try `\tikzfig{density.tikz}` then the package gets confused. When you remove the extension it works ok:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzit}
\input{mystyle.tikzstyles}
\begin{document}
  \tikzfig{density}
\end{document}
```

However, in the style file there is a definition `\tikzstyle{dashed}=[-, dashed]`, which is recursive (`dashed` is called in the definition of `dashed`) and leads to a memory error. So don't use that definition. Instead use a different name or write it in full (i.e., `\draw [-, dashed, in=120, out=60, looseness=1.25] (4.center) to (5.center);`).

Result after this correction:

[image]